# CD/DVD drive wont work?

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, optical-drive

my notebook cd/dvd drive wont play any of my cds or dvd all here is weak spin any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: Sounds like it could be dead/dying.

Comment: How old is your notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sounds like the drive is on its way out. These are relatively cheap to replace so why not try replacing it?

Answer (score 0):

Time to buy a replacement drive, perhaps?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @TomWijsman: On the contrary - the answer "buy a replacement" is a  legitimate solution to the questioner's problem with a failing drive. Comments are intended for clarification, not giving answers.